# Qual a diferença entre esses códigos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estava fazendo um código de uma roleta para um jogo que estou codando, e aconteceu isso:

- Quando eu fiz dessa forma:

  ```
  valores = list(range(100,1000,50))
  roleta = ['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo', 'Perdeu Tudo', valores,1000,1000]
  ```

quando eu faço o random.choice e ele sorteia o 'valores', ele retorna a lista inteira. Mas quando eu faço desta forma:

```
  roleta = ['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo','Perdeu Tudo'] + valores + [1000,1000]
```

Ele retorna corretamente apenas um numero do valores, quando este é sorteado? obs: o jogo é uma simulação do roda roda jequiti do sbt e aceito ajuda pra construir.

Comment: Basta fazer `print(roleta)` nos 2 casos para ver a diferença: no primeiro a lista `valores` é adicionada como um único elemento da lista `roleta` (ou seja, tem uma lista dentro de outra), já no segundo os elementos de `valores` são adicionados na lista `roleta`

Comment: Quando diz *...jogo é uma simulação do roda roda jequiti do sbt e aceito ajuda pra construir...* nós temos o [Community Ads](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8338/137387) um espaço para para anuncio de projetos open source de programação que solicitem a participação e contribuição de programadores para escrita de código. Desde que foi criado esse espaço nunca foi utilizado, se a interessar veja lá no link as regras de uso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na primeira opção, o código adiciona uma lista dentro de outra lista:

```
roleta = ['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo', 'Perdeu Tudo', valores,1000,1000]
print(roleta)
```

Output: `['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo', 'Perdeu Tudo', [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950], 1000, 1000]`

Isso é similar ao usar o `.append()`:

```
roleta = ['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo', 'Perdeu Tudo']
roleta.append(valores)
roleta.append(1000)
roleta.append(1000)
print(roleta)
```

Output: `['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo', 'Perdeu Tudo', [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950], 1000, 1000]`

---

No segundo caso, ao utilizar o `+`, é como se estivesse adicionando os elementos de uma lista (`valores`) na outra lista (`roleta`):

```
roleta = ['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo','Perdeu Tudo'] + valores + [1000,1000]
print(roleta)
```

Output: `['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo', 'Perdeu Tudo', 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1000]`

Como dito, é similar ao usar o `.extend()`:

```
roleta = ['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo','Perdeu Tudo']
roleta.extend(valores)
roleta.extend([1000,1000])
print(roleta)
```

Output: `['Passa a Vez', 'Passa a Vez', 'Perdeu Tudo', 'Perdeu Tudo', 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1000]`

> Obs.: Resposta baseada no comentario do @hkotsubo